# Change bar button color of navigation bar in GMSPlacePickerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, gmsplacepicker

I want to change the color of cancel and search icon in `GMSPlacePickerViewController` navigation bar. I tried changing the background color to test but it isn't working.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    let config = GMSPlacePickerConfig(viewport: nil)
    let placePicker = GMSPlacePickerViewController(config: config)
    placePicker.delegate = self
    placePicker.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    placePicker.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    present(placePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

[image: Current Screenshot]

Comment: First check that `placePicker.navigationController` is `nil` or not?

Comment: Try using the tintColor property of the UIBarButtonItems.